# How to make community detection with networkx module works?

Tags: python, networkx

I am working with networkx library for graph optimization problems. However, when I try running the example on [their documentation](https://python-louvain.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) it says in my PyCharm IDE after executing the example:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/PycharmProjects/testing_things.py", line 1, in <module>
    import community
ImportError: No module named community
```

Does anyone knows how to get rid of this error?  I am using Python 2.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would seem that your python installation doesn't have `community` installed.

You can install it by running:

```
pip install python-louvain
```

Cheers!

Comment: Still community comes with networkx in my humble opinion. I insatlled python-louvain but still I am getting the same error message !

Comment: @user2567806 are you using multiple python environments?  (`conda` or `virtualenv`)?  If so you have to make sure you're installing `community` in the correct environment.

Comment: I have conda installed but howerver Im not using it I guess. You are right about the env. Now it works !

Comment: Do you know which python installation PyCharm is using?  (It should be in `File > Settings > Project Interpreter `)

Comment: it is using Python 2.7.

Comment: And did you do the `pip install` on _that_ installation of python 2.7?

Comment: Yes exactly in command line and it did not work. I installed the package within the interpreter in the field of packages. It was a bit weird but now it works :)

Comment: My guess is that pycharm is using a different installation than your default python. Anyway, glad it works! Please remember to accept/up vote the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

you can use :

```
conda install python-louvain
```

Comment: it should be `python-louvain` and not `python_louvain`

Answer (score 1):

Use pip to install Python-Louvain:

```
pip install python_louvain
```

then in your script import the module directly using:

```
from community import community_louvain
```

In your code, use the function in the following way:

```
partition = community_louvain.best_partition(G)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here's the sample community detection on the famous karate club graph based on Louvain Community Detection Algorithm:**

```
# Replace this with your networkx graph loading depending on your format!
r = nx.karate_club_graph()

#first compute the best partition
partition = community.best_partition(r)

#drawing
size = float(len(set(partition.values())))
pos = nx.spring_layout(r)
count = 0

for com in set(partition.values()) :
    count = count + 1.
    list_nodes = [nodes for nodes in partition.keys()
                                if partition[nodes] == com]
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(r, pos, list_nodes, node_size = 20,
                                node_color = str(count / size))


nx.draw_networkx_edges(r, pos, alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image: Louvain Community Detection Algorithm Result Visualization]